# How to save mail in send folder using codeignator

Tags: mysql, php

I want to send email using codeignator mails are sending properly but not saving in send folder i have put code below.

```
public function sendMail()
    {
        $data=array('fromEmail'=>'xyz@gmail.com','to'=>'abc@gmail.com','cc'=>'','subject'=>'Login Count','template'=>"Any msg");    

    $localhost = array(
        '127.0.0.1',
        '::1'
    );
    $this->load->library('email');
     $config = Array(
                     /*'charset'=>'utf-8',
                     'wordwrap'=> TRUE,
                     'mailtype' => 'html'*/
                     'mailtype' => 'html',
                     'priority' => '3',
                     'charset'  => 'iso-8859-1',
                     'validate'  => TRUE ,
                     'newline'   => "\r\n",
                     'wordwrap' => TRUE

                          );
         if(in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $localhost))
         {
             $config['protocol']='smtp';
             $config['smtp_host']='ssl://smtp.office365.com';
             $config['smtp_port']='465';
             $config['smtp_user']='xyz@gmail.com';
             $config['smtp_pass']='****';
             $config['mailtype']='html';



         }
        $this->email->initialize($config);
        /*if(isset($data['fromEmail']) && $data['fromEmail']!='')
        {
            $fromEmail     =    $this->getValue($this->db->dbprefix('admin_users'),"email"," `id` = '1' ");
        }*/
        $fromName     =    'Creosouls Team';

        $this->email->clear(TRUE);
        $this->email->to($data['to']);
        if(isset($data['cc']) && $data['cc'] !='')
        {
            $this->email->cc($data['cc']);
        }    
        $this->email->from($data['fromEmail'],$fromName);
        $this->email->subject($data['subject']);
        $this->email->message($data['template']);
        $this->email->send();
        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
        pr($data);
        //  if($this->email->send())
        //     return true;
        // else
        //     return false;
}
```

Comment: That's not how SMTP email works. You are sending from the office365 server...so obviously it doesn't have access to your gmail folders. SMTP lets you put any old address in the from field. You don't have to be the owner of that address. The address doesn't even need to have a real mailbox associated with it. It's one reason that spam is such a problem. You can't do what you're asking when using SMTP. Even if you connected via Google's server (which might be a good idea if "from" is Gmail, to make your mails look less like spam) I'm pretty sure you still...

Comment: ... can't write to the send items folder because, again, you don't actually have to be the owner of the email address in order to use it in the from field. (Some mail servers may have stricter additional rules about what values they will accept based on your  identity but the core protocol doesn't prevent it). There may well be other ways to do what you want e.g. it might work over IMAP perhaps, or using the Gmail API instead, but you can't do it using SMTP